# Setting class level NSTimeInterval property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nstimeinterval

I am facing a weird issue. I have a class level NSTimeInterval property which I am synthesizing and then later on try to set it with self. but it not setting it up. But similar code is working at other place. Here, is my sample code:

```
@property NSTimeInterval interval;
@synthesize interval;

    NSTimeInterval test = 25;
    self.interval = test;
    NSLog(@"Time=%d time1=%d", self.interval, test);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSTimeInterval` is actually a double and you are trying to print an integer. It's your NSLog statement that is wrong. Use `%f` instead.

```
NSLog(@"Time=%f time1=%f", self.interval, test);
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem with your code is that you are using `%d` to print your time intervals. `NSTimeInterval` is a wrapper for the `double` type, and so requires `%f` to print. This will cause some funny behaviour in your log statement.